# Android on phone changes angle switch activity

Tags: android

I have tried to find the solution but I didn't even know what to call this operation and maybe my question title wrong. anyway , I want to do something (switch activity, show hide any element) when the phone changes its angle like I flip the phone upside down or just change the angle. just like when we do something on chake listener. Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Use SensorManager to calculate the phone rotation and depend on the rotation do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override your Activity's [`onConfigurationChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method. Then, you add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your Manifest.

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:name=".your.package">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an app that required a different activity to run based on the orientation(portrait/landscape). What I did was created an intermediate class/activity that checks for the orientation of the device and then routes it to the corresponding activity.

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;//get current orientation

if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ) {
        //portrait layout        
    } else {
        //landscape layout
    }
```